# Why doesn't this python if statement work?

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I'm trying to figure out why I can't run the code right after the number 5.

here is the code

```
if 2 < 5
    print('Five is greater than two')
```

I tried deleting all of the spaces I could until it became one line of code. I was expecting for a smooth python start but is hard to do it as a beginner.

Comment: I recommend reading this [beginner tutorial for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Answer (score 3):

You have to put a colon after "if 2 < 5".

```
if 2 < 5:
    print('Five is greater than two')
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon (:) after the condition in the if statement. Here is the corrected code:

```
if 2 < 5:
  print("five is greater than 2")
```

Comment: How is this different from the already posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77382160/16770846)?

Comment: At the time I started answering, no one had posted a response.